# How can I disable Siri for making reminders and calendar items?

Tags: iphone, unlock, siri

I would like Siri not to be able to make reminders and calendar items without asking for the lock screen password.

When I ask Siri to create a new reminder, I would like to ask it to unlock my phone first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option is to completely disable Siri when your phone is locked.

To do this, in the settings:
Click on `General`
Click on `Passcode Lock`
Scroll down and uncheck Siri under the heading `ALLOW ACCESS WHEN LOCKED:`

Comment: It's not a perfect solution. I expected there to be an option to customize exactly what Siri can do when the iPhone is locked. I decided to go with your solution and disable Siri in the lock screen entirely, because I really don't want people to be able to make calendar items, phone calls, make notes, set alarms, etc. when I'm not around.

Comment: It would be great if we could customize exactly what can and can't be done, but unfortunately for the time being that cannot be done. Hopefully that functionality will be implemented in the future!